# How to Fix JUnit Allure Issue?

Tags: junit, allure

I'm dealing with a test task to build some JUnit tests upon numbers in a .txt file. The project is built in Maven, i use Win7 and Idea 2016.1.1.
Also I have to export results to Yandex Allure with values from .txt as test parameters.
The problem is that when i perform an unsuccessful test, the report is not generated despite it works ok when the test is successful.
I'm totally stuck, spent 4 or 5 hours trying to solve it.

Please tell me what do i do wrong?
Here is the POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Tel</groupId>
    <artifactId>Entry_Task</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${allure-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <properties>
        <allure-junit-adaptor.version>1.4.23</allure-junit-adaptor.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
        <allure-maven-plugin.version>2.5</allure-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.18</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>${allure-junit-adaptor.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Test file:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestLine_001 extends Assert {
    @Test
    public void factorial() {
        assertTrue("z"=="p");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\Users\Stas\IdeaProjects\SBT_Entry_Task "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\apache-maven-3.3.9" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\m2.conf" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2016.1.1 clean test site
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Entry_Task 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Entry_Task ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Users\Stas\IdeaProjects\SBT_Entry_Task\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Entry_Task ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Entry_Task ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\Users\Stas\IdeaProjects\SBT_Entry_Task\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Entry_Task ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Users\Stas\IdeaProjects\SBT_Entry_Task\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Entry_Task ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\Users\Stas\IdeaProjects\SBT_Entry_Task\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test (default-test) @ Entry_Task ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\Users\Stas\IdeaProjects\SBT_Entry_Task\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Running TestLine_001
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.258 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestLine_001
factorial(TestLine_001)  Time elapsed: 0.204 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
    at TestLine_001.factorial(TestLine_001.java:7)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  TestLine_001.factorial:7->Assert.assertTrue:52->Assert.assertTrue:41->Assert.fail:86 null



Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.789 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-02T14:00:03+06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/255M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test (default-test) on project Entry_Task: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\Users\Stas\IdeaProjects\SBT_Entry_Task\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] Maven execution terminated abnormally (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it is Maven feature - when you run several goals it stops on first failure (which usually makes sense, e.g. "mvn clean install").

Just run goals separately:

```
mvn clean test
mvn site
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
```

to maven-surefire-plugin config

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
     <configuration>
           <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
           <argLine>....
```